# Can I estimate those models with the plm package

Tags: panel, plm, random-effects

I want to compare the estimations of the following models but I don't know if I can estimate models (5) with the plm package:

1/ pooled -> Yit

```
fit.pooling <- plm(form, data = pdata, model = "pooling")
```

2/ Within (ind/time/both effects) -> Yit - Yi. / Yit - Yt. / Yit - Yi. - Yt.

```
fit.fe <- plm(form, data = pdata, model = "within", effect="ind"/"time"/"twoways")
```

3/ Between (ind/time effects)-> Yi. / Yt.

```
fit.bet <- plm(form, data = pdata, model = "between", effect="ind"/"time")
```

4/ Random effect (ind/time/both effects)-> Yit - a*Yi. / Yit - a*Yt. / Yit - a*Yi. - b*Yt.

```
fit.re <- plm(form, data = pdata, model = "random", effect="ind"/"time"/"twoways")
```

5/ Random effect with fixed time effect or Random effect with fixed ind effect ? -> Yit - a*Yi. - Yt. / Yit - a*Yt. - Yi.

Can I estimate those models with plm package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split 5) in 5.1) and 5.2):

5.1) random *individual* effect with fixed time effect

5.2) random *time* effect with fixed individual effect.

This type of model, Baltagi calls a mixed error component model in his text book and - I think - EViews calls it a mixed model (but it is not to be mistaken as a mixed effect model in the MLE context).

Both can be fitted with plm like this:

5.1)

`fit.mix5.1 <- plm(<your formula + factor(timeindex)>, data = pdata, model = "random", effect = "individual")`

5.2)

`fit.mix5.2 <- plm(<your formula + factor(indindex)>, data = pdata, model = "random", effect = "time")`

Where factor(timeindex) or factor(indindex) is the time or individual index as a factor, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I've obtained weird results with the following error message : "Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[17,17] = 0". If I delete all but one variable from the model, the code works but I still obtain the following warning messages : " Warning messages:
1: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)" Do you know the source of the error? Thanks again.